# Change root to public inside sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.1

I work in an agency and I created a subdomain in order to show our customers some code examples we can provide, all my applications are made in Laravel 5.1, and each application is being placed in a sub-directory, like this:

```
scripts.domain.com
   /image-filter
      /public
   /facebook-image-app
      /public
   /twitter-integration
      /public
   /instagram-wall
      /public
```

`I need to point the root into the public folder...`

I've tried this, but it didn't work as expected:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^scripts.domain.com/image-filter$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.scripts.domain.com/image-filter$
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: I would recommend using virtual hosts and serving them from subdomains

Comment: @Jeff I have been developing a lot of applications in the last days, and our hosting has some problems, whenever I need to create a subdomain open a ticket and it's kind of boring, then I would put everything on the same subdomain, this can help in the organization too...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} scripts.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/?(.*)$ $1/public/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Put this in root of public_html or inside each sub-directory?

Comment: kind of works, it returns me a 404 error, but it does not show the desired content

Comment: It should be in `public_html`. You will have to provide more informations concerning your virtualhost configuration if it doesn't work. Please edit your question.